# How to handle "Up" button?

Tags: android

How to handle "Up" button (SDK version 11+)? I am referring to the one at the top of screen, that holds the application icon.

In Android Design articles it was named as "Up button", but I didn't found it (or similar) in KeyEvent fields.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Implement `onOptionsItemSelected()` and watch for `android.R.id.home` "menu" events, as is described in [the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // do something useful
            return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Comment: Hey i have the same problem. But do you know how to get the little arrow? I open a new Activity with the actionbar and i want to use this "up-button" to go back to the main screen. For the SearchView it switch automaticaly the button to the one with the little arrow, but how?

Comment: @Mirko: If you are referring to what I think that you are referring to, try `setHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, called on your `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 1):

First change your AndroidManifest.xml file to have a parent activity declared. Eg

```
    <activity android:name=".theory"
              android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/theory"
        />
    <activity android:name=".experimental"
              android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/exp"
        />
```

Do this for all the activities other than the MainActivity.
Note the parentActivityName xml code

Then go to the respective java files and add the following code

```
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You have you up button enabled now.